# Why is the target table not recognized as table in select insert into procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

We are building a table TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110_L0 from table TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110 using the select insert into but the target table is not recognized as table.

```
create or replace procedure gla_first_step()
language plpgsql
as $$
-- declare TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110_L0 varchar;
begin

select *,
CASE WHEN (B110TrialBalanceCodeText1406 LIKE N'%DATA%' and B110TrialBalanceCodeText1406 not LIKE N'%DATA%'
                                        and B110TrialBalanceCodeText1406 not LIKE N'%DATA%') OR
          (B110TrialBalanceCodeText1406 LIKE N'%DATA%' and B110TrialBalanceCodeText1406 not like  N'%DATA%') OR
          B110TrialBalanceCodeText1406 LIKE N'%DATA%' OR
          B110TrialBalanceCodeText1406 LIKE '%EXPENSE%' OR
          B110TrialBalanceCodeText1406 LIKE '%INCOME%' 
          THEN 'P' else 'B' end as accountType
INTO  TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110_L0
from  TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110;

end;
$$
```

We get:

```
ERROR:  "tbl_bkmvdata_131_b110_l0" is not a known variable
LINE 15: INTO  TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110_L0
               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 645
```

Just to make sure everything else works.. if we release the comment from
`declare TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110_L0 varchar;`

We get

```
CREATE PROCEDURE

Query returned successfully in 43 msec.
```

Comment: 1) You answered your own question, you have to `DECLARE` a variable before using it. 2) Per [Single row result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) `SELECT ... INTO` means something different in `plpgsql` then here [Select Into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html). See *Tip Note that this interpretation of SELECT with INTO is quite different from PostgreSQL's regular SELECT INTO command, ...*

Comment: Thank you I've clarified my question.

Comment: Read the information at [Single row result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW). Bottom line you cannot use `SELECT ... INTO` in `plpgsql` in that manner. You will have to use `CREATE TABLE  ... AS SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you. If you want kindly answer and I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per docs [43.5.3. Executing a Command with a Single-Row Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

> SELECT select_expressions INTO [STRICT] target FROM ...;

<...>

> Tip

> Note that this interpretation of SELECT with INTO is quite different from PostgreSQL's regular SELECT INTO command, wherein the INTO target is a newly created table. If you want to create a table from a SELECT result inside a PL/pgSQL function, use the syntax CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT.

This means you will need to use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` to build a new table from an old in the function. When you uncommented `-- declare TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110_L0 varchar;` then the `plpgsql` form of `SELECT INTO` was used and the result of the query was assigned to `TBL_bkmvdata_131_B110_L0`.